# Is LESS-build compatible with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

im migrating from Sublime text 2 to Sublime text 3, but some packages dont work, as Less-Build.. When i try to build my .less files (ctrl+b) the console shows me this:

> [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
>   [cmd: ['C:\Otros programas\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages\LESS-build\dotless.Compiler.exe', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\santa_anita\web\bundles\almacen\css\layout.less', 'layout.css']]
>   [dir: C:\xampp\htdocs\santa_anita\web\bundles\almacen\css]
>   [path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\NetSarang;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\xampp\php;C:\xampp\mysql\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Nmap;C:\SocketeQ\windowsandroid_root\system\bin;C:\SocketeQ\windowsandroid_root\system\lib;C:\Users\Desarrollo\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73]
>   [Finished]

How can i configure the route for the less compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i copied the LESS-build folder from (Sublime Text 2 folder)\Data\Packages to (SublimeText 3 folder)\Data\Packages and it works :/

Answer (score 1):

LESS-build compatible with Sublime Text3 ? :) I have the same problem and also lost a few hours trying to fix this but I finally found livereload it very grateful no more care about compiling.

It is done automaticaly :) goodluck

Comment: First you have to install livereload [download from here][1] and view tut from livereload (when you r working with any project just run livereload and put project folder in to livereload go to next tab call actions file
turn on compile less sas... you r done:) 

when you save less file it'll complie for you :) goodluck!


  [1]: http://livereload.com/

Answer (score 0):

The path for the less compiler is in **LESS.sublime-build** which should be within a LESS-build folder inside your *%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages* folder.

I had trouble installing LESS-build for Sublime Text 3 and ended up using Git instead of the Package Control plugin so your file location may be a little different.

After figuring that out I was able to get it up and running in ST3 and it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install livereload [download from here](http://livereload.com/) and view tut from livereload (when you r working with any project just run livereload and put project folder in to livereload go to next tab call actions file
turn on compile less sas... you r done:)

when you save less file it'll complie for you :) goodluck!

Comment: Note: when you buld something in livereload save but it not compile check your code first maybe you write somethings wrong with your code :) try to test your code here: http://lesstester.com/